# How can I restore the original Windows 7 fonts from its DVD?

Tags: windows-7, fonts

I replaced the original Windows 7 fonts with some bad fonts!

How can I acquire the original Windows 7 fonts from its DVD and extract them? I looked on the DVD but couldn't find any folders named `fonts`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you extract the `Sources\install.wim` file, you can open it with [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org) (available on [Ninite](http://ninite.com/sevenzip/) for quick installing).

Then go to `\1\Windows\Fonts` and extract.

[image]

`Install.Wim` contains every edition of Windows (Home, Ultimate e.t.c.), Each number refers to a different installation.

That being said, the fonts from all editions are the same, so it doesn't matter what folder you use.

I would recommend you go to safemode, and simply extract to a temporary folder, then overwrite all the fonts in `c:\windows\fonts` with these... or manually click on every one and do install.

Comment: thanks for answer | but what do the other folders do ? mean -> 2,3,4,5 ?

Comment: besides what about these fonts names after extarct -> can i move them (for replace) with unnatural names in fonts folder ?

Comment: @moonlight - Updated answer, written a little more.