# Chrome and Firefox displays an italic font on many websites

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome, fonts

Chrome and Firefox shows a very annoying font on many blog websites, while the same websites display the proper font on other PCs (on Chrome and Firefox).

Here is a screenshot of http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/:

[image: screenshot of timesofindia.indiatimes.com, with strange fonts]

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate SP1. Chrome Version 31.0.1650.57 m and Firefox 25.0. The websites should display the normal font which is default specified in their website or browsers' default. Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and give us more details? Like, what operating system you use, what versions of the browsers, how the websites are *supposed* to look like, if it happens on all sites or just particular websites, etc?

Comment: Which OS? Have you tried removing any custom fonts you've added to the system?  What font does the page code/CSS say it's trying to use?    What exactly do you expect them to look like (can you give us an example site to check for ourselves)?

Comment: @techie007 the website url is http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/ currently the example i have.screen shot from same website i have linked to this question.

Answer (score 1):

That is NOT a standard Windows 7 font.  You've most likely overwritten a Windows system font with this odd-ball one.

The site in question is styled to use the "Georgia" font, which [is a standard Windows 7 font](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1571).

You may want to try restoring your fonts form the Windows 7 DVD: [How can I restore the original Windows 7 fonts from its DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/328321/how-can-i-restore-the-original-windows-7-fonts-from-its-dvd)

Comment: still the same issue. I did the same as you suggested to do. I followed the link2 you provided to me

Comment: Internet explorer showing correct font, I don't know whether it was displaying it correctly previously.